# cannot login using system/manager in oracle 12c Realease II database

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, oracle12c

I am trying to login to oracle sqlplus using system/manager but unable to do.

I logged in using `sys` user and then ran

`ALTER USER SYSTEM IDENTIFIED BY manager;`

It said user changed but then when I did

`CONN SYSTEM/manager`

It says invalid login/password.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure the sec_case_sensitive_logon parameter set to false

Answer (score 0):

Please, post your SQL*Plus session which shows what *exactly* you did and how Oracle responded - just like in my example:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> alter user system identified by manager;

User altered.

SQL> conn system/manager
Connected.
SQL>
```